# "get around regulation" VS "get around regulations"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. Some people in the financial sector tried to get around **regulation**.
> 2. Some people in the financial sector tried to get around **regulations**.

It I want to convey the message that certain people want to evade regulation(s) and do whatever they want, which one should I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Either word can be used here.** The difference is only subtle and probably does not matter in your context.

Using the singular "regulation" implies that the people are circumventing the concept in general, i.e. government oversight.

Using the plural "regulations" implies that the people are circumventing multiple specific rules or requirements, such as the Clean Air Act or labor laws. (The plural can be used here even if the people are circumventing all regulations.)

Again, there is little effective difference in your context. However the difference matters in the example below.

> I hate **these regulations**. They do not do enough to protect the environment.

In this case, the person probably approves of regulation as a general concept but does not like some particular regulations.

Comment: so regulation as a non-countable noun can be referred to as a general concept, while regulation as a countable noun can indicate some or all of the rules and laws. Am I right?